# Anchors are not clickable somehow

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to make that website for YouTube views and like bot and the logo isn't clickable somehow.

```css
navbar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: gray;
}

.navbar ul li {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 50px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
}

li:first-child {
  background-image: url(bolbol.png);
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  text-indent: -1400px;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

li:nth-child(2) {
  position: relative;
  top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Logo</a></li>
    <li>Liorgay</li>
    <li>Nevo King</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6L3jak0s/

Comment: What is the purpose of ```text-indent: -1400px```? Of course you can't click the logo. It's off the screen.

Comment: its because the photo is from background-image on li so its make the text disappear

Comment: Those images don't copy over to these code snippets, so we just see blank.

Comment: Usually the problem in cases like this is because some invisible element overlays your anchor. Have you used your browser's document inspector to check for that? Without a proper demo I can't really help.

Comment: Ive added a js fiddle for yall so you can know what im trying to solve better

Comment: your only one link in your code seems clickable to me , for the code, i would go with inline-block instead float ... https://jsfiddle.net/r7udwo4t/

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is to make things look like a header, it's better with flexbox. Something like this maybe..

```css
.navbar {
  display: flex;
  background-color: gray;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  justify-content:space-between;
  align-items:center;
}

.navbar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;
    align-items:center;
}

.navbar ul li {
  margin-right: 50px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
}

li:first-child {
  background-image: url(bololo.jpg);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.navbar a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="index.html">Logo</a>
  <ul>
    <li>Liorgay</li>
    <li>Nevo King</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this property "text-indent: -1400px;" from this rule "li:first-child Rule".

and then add the following CSS.

```
.navbar li a {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    text-indent: -1400px;
}
```

Comment: inline-block is needed to size the a tag, but text-indent is used to remove the text and only show the bg.